# User UI feedback after clicking on a react-router-dom <Link/>?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, styled-components

Here's what I'm dealing with:

- Single page app built with `react` + `react-router-dom`
- User clicks on a `<Link to={"/new-page-route"}/>`
- URL changes and my `<Route/>` starts rendering a new `<Component/>`

I mean, React is fast, but my new component takes a while to render because it's a whole new page. So it should take something between 200 and 400ms. And if I get no UI feedback, it feels that my click has not worked.

I need some kind of UI feedback so my user's know their click has been fired and something is going on. I don't think I need loaders or anything, but **something to show that the click has been "accepted" by the UI.**

In theory that could be handled by CSS using:

- `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: #SOMECOLOR`
- `active: #SOMECOLOR`

But somehow, when the URL changes and the new render begins, **the browser is not being able to paint those CSS results to the screen**, at least this is the behavior on Chrome and Firefox. It gets kind of weird, sometimes I see the `tap-highlight` and the `active-change` but almost always I don't see it.

**NOTE:** This is not the [300ms default delay on mobile](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away) that waits for the double tap. I've dealt with that using the appropriate tags.

What I thought about doing is:

- Stop using the `<Link/>` component and use a normal `<a/>`.
- Create a `clicked` state to be update after the `click` event
- Call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent normal behavior of the `<a/>` navigation
- Use the `clicked` state to render some new styles for the UI feedback
- Fire `history.push("/new-page-route")` on a `useEffect` after `clicked` state has become true

Something like:

```
const newUrl = "/new-page-route";
const [clicked,setClicked] = useState(false);

const history = useHistory();      // HOOK FROM react-router-dom

function handleLinkClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  setClicked(true);
}

useEffect(() => {

  if (clicked === true) {

    history.push(newUrl);

    // OR MAYBE ADD A TIMEOUT TO BE EXTRA SURE THAT THE FEEDBACK WILL BE PAINTED
    // BECAUSE I'VE SEEN THE BROWSER NOT BEING ABLE TO PAINT IF I DON'T GIVE IT SOME EXTRA TIME
    setTimeout(() => history.push(newUrl),100);

  }

},[clicked,history]);


// USE THE clicked STATE TO RENDER THE UI FEEDBACK (CHANGE TEXT COLOR, WHATEVER I NEED);
```

**QUESTION**

Has anyone had this issue before? What is a good way of solving this? I guess that in theory the browser should be able to paint before the new render begins, but this is not what I'm getting.

**SANDBOX WITH THE ISSUE**

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-monad-4fwoc    <=== CLICK HERE TO SEE THE CODE

https://4fwoc.csb.app   <=== CLICK HERE TO SEE THE RESULT ONLY

- On desktop: I'm able to see the `BLUE` background for the `active` state when clicking the link
- On mobile: I don't see any CSS change when clicking the links. Unless I tap AND HOLD
- Comments: Imagine that your component takes a while to render. Without any UI feedback, it feels that you haven't clicked at all, even though it is rendering on background.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./styles.css";

const HOME = "/";
const ROUTE1 = "/route1";
const ROUTE2 = "/route2";

const LS = {};

// REGULAR CSS RULES FOR THE className="link" ARE ON "./styles.css"

LS.Link_LINK = styled(Link)`
  color: black;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: red;
  &:active {
    background-color: blue;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={HOME} component={Home} />
          <Route exact path={ROUTE1} component={Component1} />
          <Route exact path={ROUTE2} component={Component2} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am Home</div>
      <LS.Link_LINK to={ROUTE1}>Route 1 (using styled-components)</LS.Link_LINK>
      <br />
      <Link className={"link"} to={ROUTE1}>
        Route 1 (using regular CSS)
      </Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Component1() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am Component1</div>
      <LS.Link_LINK to={ROUTE2}>Route 2 (using styled-components)</LS.Link_LINK>
      <br />
      <Link className={"link"} to={ROUTE2}>
        Route 2 (using regular CSS)
      </Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Component2() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am Component2</div>
      <LS.Link_LINK to={HOME}>Home (using styled-components)</LS.Link_LINK>
      <br />
      <Link className={"link"} to={HOME}>
        Home (using regular CSS)
      </Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use two `loading` phases.

1. Use [lazy
   loading](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)
   when loading the "heavy" page and display a
   [skeleton](https://uxdesign.cc/what-you-should-know-about-skeleton-screens-a820c45a571a)
   component as a fallback to show the user that something is loading.
2. Use a component/redux state loading indicator for when your page is
   loading data from apis

Trying to achive that with react-router links is not the best way because routing happends instantly, it is not the thing that stalls your application. Api calls and multiple re-renders cause an application to behave slowly.

Comment: Thanks, Tasos. There are no APIs being called during this route change. But it renders multiple components, that render multiple dropdowns, and svg chart, and some other stuff, so it takes a while. The data for all that is already present when the route is being changed. It's not a huge delay. It's still much faster than fetching the page from the server and I'm ok with letting the user wait 200-400ms. I just need to be clear that his click was "accepted" and is being "processed", or something like that. That is why I've though of a `tap-highlight` or something. But it does not work.

Comment: This is only a problem on Mobile devices, that have less CPU power. On desktop the page change is basically real-time, so I don't need a click feedback. The feedback is the page change itself. I think I would be adding extra complexity unnecessarily if I were to implement lazy-loading and multiple render cascades just for that. Specially with no API calls involved. What do you think?

Comment: Since the url changes and a new component is being loaded you cannot do much, what would work for you is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-loading-bar and I also found this that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40989121/5605822