# Showing a loading screen with circular progress while site loads in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, loading

Hey as im new to reactjs can someone tell me how can this be achieved? I want to show a loading screen with circular progress while the site loads and when the site loads the site should be revealed and loading screen should fade out

Comment: Render a circular progress if the data your fetching doesn't exist yet. Is there something more you are looking for? If your talking about the initial loading of the react app there isnt much you can do about that since it would have to be loaded for you to render anything.

Comment: Yes im talking about the initial load.So i have to show some loading screen with some progress bar and fade out after certain time right?

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987309/react-display-loading-screen-while-dom-is-rendering