# How can I create a loading while initially downloading and executing a react project?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to create a loading splash screen that is animating while the rest of the react project is getting rendered?

I'm guessing this would be done through server-side rendering but I am clueless as to how.

Comment: Previously answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987309/react-display-loading-screen-while-dom-is-rendering

Answer (score 1):

It is possible

Add like this.

Edit these index.html in your public folder

Add this in head. This css will make the loader center align

```
<style>
      .img-loader-init img { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto; }
</style>
```

and in the body

```
<div id="root">
        <div class="img-loader-init">
            <img src="loader.gif" alt="loader">
        </div>
</div>
```

loader.gif should be under public folder.